# Kibana /etc/init.d scripts

Tags: sles, init.d, sles11, kibana

I am having a hard time adapting the `init.d` start up scripts I have found for Kibana on the internet.

I am experienced with RedHat/Centos but we have standardized on Suse Enterpise Linux here at work. So I need to *port* the `init.d` scripts I have been using to work with SLES.

I don't have access to the machine with the scripts, and they aren't throwing any errors; at least not any that I can figure out how to detect. But they also don't start up Kibana and keep it running.

I can start Kibana from the command line manually, but that won't work in a production environment. I would rather use the blessed `kibana-daemon.rb` script and a proper `init.d` script to kick that off.

I wanted to go ahead and reach out to see if anyone had a working script for SLES.

*As soon as I get back to my other machine I will update this question with the specific scripts and any errors I can find.*

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is much easier to use `mod_passenger` and rely on the `httpd` init scripts, instead.

This is a working example from an older Kibana version, you might need to adapt it to your needs:

```
# vim:fdm=marker:syn=apache:ts=2
# VHOST KIBANA {{{
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
  ServerAdmin "sysadmin@company.com"
  ServerName "kibana.crapsteak.org"
  DocumentRoot "/opt/org/kibana/Kibana-x.y.z/public/"
  ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -f ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kibana/error.log.%Y%m%d 86400"
  CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -f ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kibana/access.log.%Y%m%d 86400" logstash_json
  HostnameLookups Off
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ServerSignature On
  RackBaseURI /
  <Directory "/opt/org/kibana/Kibana-0.2.0/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 10.0.0 x.y.z.0/24
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# }}}
```

Comment: I don't have Apache on this machine and Ruby is the one language out of all the mainstream languages that I know that I don't *"do"*; so I had not considered this. Good advice.